# Is it possible to Block/Disable Factory Reset programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, reset

So far searching on Google and cracking head on this, I didn't find as such relevant answer for this but find one app"Seqrite MDM" which is saying that they are able to Block the Factory Reset . I am still wondering whether it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for specific manufacturers and devices.  For example, Samsung has an SDK here: https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/RestrictionPolicy.html#allowFactoryReset(boolean)  which will control access to that.  Some other manufacturers have similar functionality but as far as I'm aware stock Android does not support that.

Stock Android does now support this using device owners mode.